# Maximum skeleton muscle mass in human body

Tags: bodybuilding, workout, gym, gymnastics

I am wondering whether there is a way or formula, which considers all elements (sex, age, weight, height etc.), to calculate the maximum skeleton mass one can obtain through the workout in the gym?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute limit to human muscle growth is something to which there is no real answer. Probably because no one's ever tested it and because it would be very hard, if not impossible, to do so. Just because no one may have reached a certain level of lean muscle mass, doesn't mean its impossible, but when someone does reach that level, whose to say somone else couldn't eventually go further. Even with chemical enhancement, perfect diet and perfect training for decades, genetics could make one person able to build more muscle than the other.

When only considering natural athletes, it's often considered the the limit is an FFMI(Fat Free Mass Index) of 25-26. FFMI is a numerical value that the takes into consideration height, weight and body-fat %, with a number tending upwards for more lean muscle or less body-fat.

Comment: Those FFMI predictions/limits are intended to describe those who are the most genetically predisposed to gaining a lot of muscle. They are not realistic targets or predictors for the average person.

Comment: Yeah  I know that, but answering a question like this, it's impossible to factor in the individual variation of your genetic predisposition to muscle growth and so I just stated the generally perceived limit of natural athletes as a whole.

Comment: @Ethan Thank you for the answer and suggestion. In other words, FFMI method cannot consider one's age and gender to estimate the lean mass. Am I correct?

Comment: @David Scarlett Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ethan I'd just put that as the answer to the original question! "No, it's impossible to factor in the individual variation of your genetic predisposition to muscle growth."

Comment: @Kieran I'd assume there are figures of high-level athlete gender differences out there and FFMI is generally calibrated for males. Now substract the roughly 10% per decade muscle loss due to aging (sarcopenia) starting around 25ish, and there you have it

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Thank you very much for the answer and suggestion.

Comment: FWIW, there is a branch of statistics called "Extreme Value Theory" that is used to predict unobserved maxima from sub-maximal observations (e.g. for estimating the level of a "1000 year" flood), so there would be a valid basis for estimating the absolute limit from data that could be readily collected.

Comment: @Dikran Marsupial Thank you for the suggestion.